# How to get line count/view model line count after text in editor is wrapped?

Tags: visual-studio-code, monaco-editor

I have a use case where I need to know the actual number of lines in the editor when the text is word wrapped. In previous versions of monaco-editor, there used to be `editor.getViewModel().getLineCount()` or `editor.getViewLineCount()` functions to do that but in the version 0.34 that I am using, there's no such public function.

I inspected the editor instance in the browser console and I found that `getViewModel()` is now an internal function with new name `_getViewModel()`. Is there a public api on editor instance that I can use to get the line account after text in editor is wrapped? If not then is it safe to use `_getViewModel()`? Are there any plans to deprecate/delete the `_getViewModel()`?